# .NET custom Json converter for list or single item

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

my goal is to use `System.text.Json` to parse a response from the rest api.
The response returns one or more items - but if only one item is returned, there are no brackets `[]` surrounding it (which makes it hard to parse).

**The deserialization:**

```cs
// i need a list here to process data
var response = JsonSeralizer.Deseralize<IList<ExampleResponse>>(content);
```

**Example response 1:**

```json
[
 {
  "Status": "Healthy"
 },
 {
  "Status": "Healthy"
 }
]
```

**Example response 2:**

```json
{
 "Status": "Healthy"
}
```

How can i write a custom converter using `JsonConverter<T>`, which can parse a single item or an entire list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a custom converter (inherit from JsonConverter)

Though with this case I would've probably just wrote

```
var isList = content.StartsWith("[");
var response = isList ? JsonSeralizer.Deseralize<IList<ExampleResponse>>(content)
 : new IList<ExampleResponse> { JsonSeralizer.Deseralize<ExampleResponse>(content) };
```

Comment: I'd prefer to have this in a converter, but i think it will do the job for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the output of the REST API to force it to always return an array, you can check the string before parsing it, and add brackets. Then parse it.

I made this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhZIKq

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `content` starts with '{' in that case Deserialize to Single item and after that create new `List` from the single item.

```
List<ExampleResponse> response;
if (content.StartsWith("{"){
   response = new List<ExampleResponse>(){
               JsonSerilizer.Deserialize<ExampleResponse>(content)
             };
else
{
    response = JsonSeralizer.Deseralize<IList<ExampleResponse>>(content);
}
```